# How can I regroup my two for loops into one with only a tiny difference between the two?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have the following code with the only difference being the j and the I position in my list. Is there any way to make it better by writing a function or something like that because I can't quite figure it out?

```
for i in range(dimension):
    for j in range(dimension - 4):
        k = 1
        while k < 5 and gameboard[i][j+k] == gameboard[i][j]:
            k += 1
        if k == 5:
            winner = gameboard[i][j]

for i in range(dimension):
    for j in range(dimension - 4):
        k = 1
        while k < 5 and gameboard[j+k][i] == gameboard[j][i]:
            k += 1
        if k == 5:
            winner = gameboard[j][i]
```

Comment: side note - with this code you can overwrite `winner` multiple times. The question doesn't provide any context, but I'm guessing you should stop the execution after a `winner` is found (e.g., `return` from the function, `break`, etc)

Comment: This is lots of work, especially if you allow a big game board. I suppose the winner can be only the player who performed the recent move. If so, you can just test four consecutive positions in four directions from the place of that last move. That would be much more complicated code but much less work to do.

Comment: I know thank you but it is not a problem in this case because it represents a connect 5 game so only one person wins, my gameboard is either a win for one player or for none. No two players can win at the same time.

Comment: The thing is I want to check it afterward. I have the final position and I want to know if 5 are connected.

Answer (score 1):

You could merge the two loops by inserting an additional nested loop that handles the permutations of i and j and the corresponding dimension deltas:

```
for i in range(dimension):
    for j in range(dimension - 4):
        for i,j,di,dj in [ (i,j,0,1), (j,i,1,0) ]:
            k = 1
            while k < 5 and gameboard[i+k*di][j+k*dj] == gameboard[i][j]:
                k += 1
            if k == 5:
                winner = gameboard[i][j]
```

**Generalized for all directions**

Alternatively you could create a function that tells you if there is a win in a given direction and use that in a loop.

```
def directionWinner(board,i,j,di,dj):
    player,pi,pj = board[i][j],i,j
    # if player == empty: return
    for _ in range(4):
        pi,pj = pi+di, pj+dj
        if pi not in range(len(board)): return
        if pj not in range(len(board)): return
        if board[pi][pj] != player:     return  
    return player
```

Then use it to check all directions:

```
for pos in range(dimensions*dimensions):
    i,j = divmod(pos,dimensions)
    for direction in [ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,-1) ]:
        winner = directionWinner(gameboard,i,j,*direction)
        if winner is not None: break
    else: continue; break
```

The directions are represented by the increase/decrease in vertical and horizontal coordinates (deltas) for each step of one.  So `[ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,-1) ]` gives you "down", "across", "diagonal 1", diagonal 2" respectively.

**Checking only from last move**

The same idea can be used to check for a winner from a specific position (e.g. checking if last move is a win):

```
# count how may consecutive in a given direction (and its inverse)
def countDir(board,i,j,di,dj,inverted=False):
    player,pi,pj = board[i][j],i,j
    count  = 0
    while pi in range(len(board) and pj in range(len(board)):
          if board[pi][pj] == player: count += 1
          else: break
          pi, pj = pi+di, pj+dj 
    if not inverted: 
       count += countDir(board,i,j,-di,-dj,True)-1
    return count

 def winnerAt(board,i,j):
     for direction in [ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,-1) ]:
         if countDir(board,i,j,*direction)>=5:
             return board[i,j]
```

Then, after playing at position i,j, you can immediately know if the move won the game:

```
if winnerAt(gameboard,i,j) is not None:
    print(gameboard[i][j],"wins !!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe a trivial change, but why don't you just put the second check in the first loop just by swapping indices and using another variable for the while part? I mean something like this:

```py
def check_winner(gameboard, dimension):
    for i in range(dimension):
        for j in range(dimension - 4):
            # perform the first check
            k = 1
            while k < 5 and gameboard[i][j+k] == gameboard[i][j]:
                k += 1
            if k == 5:
                return gameboard[i][j]
            # and the second check
            l = 1
            while l < 5 and gameboard[j + k][i] == gameboard[j][i]:
                l += 1
            if l == 5:
                return gameboard[j][i]
```

Anyways, it's cleaner to just return if you found the winner, and avoid redundancy.